# section tag inside unordered list or around?

Tags: html, html-lists

i'm still very confused about the use of "section" in html 5. I'd just like to which of the below solutions is the better one. The contents inside the list are not related to each other. So do I have to give a section to each of them or do I have to put it all in one section. See below:

Solution one:

```
<ul>
<li>
    <section>
        <header>
            <h2>Services</h2>
        </header>
        <img src="img/foto/testpic1.jpg" alt="" title="" border="0"/>
        <p>This is text</p>
    </section>
</li>
<li>
    <section>
        <header>
        <h2>Products</h2>
        </header>
        <img src="img/foto/testpic2.jpg" alt="" title="" border="0"/>
        <p>This is text</p>
    </section>
</li>
<li>
    <section>
        <header>
        <h2>Contacts</h2>
        </header>
        <img src="img/foto/testpic3.jpg" alt="" title="" border="0"/>
        <p>This is text</p>
    </section>
</li>
</ul>
```

Solution two:

```
<section>
<ul>
    <li>
        <header>
            <h2>Services</h2>
        </header>
        <img src="img/foto/testpic1.jpg" alt="" title="" border="0"/>
        <p>This is text</p> 
    </li>
    <li>
        <header>
            <h2>Products</h2>
        </header>
        <img src="img/foto/testpic2.jpg" alt="" title="" border="0"/>
        <p>This is text</p> 
    </li>
    <li>
        <header>
            <h2>Contacts</h2>
        </header>
        <img src="img/foto/testpic3.jpg" alt="" title="" border="0"/>
        <p>This is text</p>
    </li>
</ul>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you need the list (`<ul>`) in the first place here. I'd remove it since it makes sense to use it for actual lists only ( or list-like elements, i.e. menus ) which is not the case here.

Now about the `<section>`. According to specs:

> *The `<section>` element represents a generic section of a document or application. A section, in this context, is a thematic grouping of content, **typically with a heading.***

Which eliminates your solution #2.

More:

> *Authors are encouraged to use the `<article>` element instead of the `<section>` element when it would make sense to syndicate the contents of the element.*

So In your case I's do this:

```
<article>
    <header>
        <h2>Services</h2>
    </header>
    <img src="img/foto/testpic1.jpg" alt="" title="" border="0"/>
    <p>This is text</p> 
</article>
<article>
    <header>
        <h2>Products</h2>
    </header>
    <img src="img/foto/testpic2.jpg" alt="" title="" border="0"/>
    <p>This is text</p> 
</article>
<article>
    <header>
        <h2>Contacts</h2>
    </header>
    <img src="img/foto/testpic3.jpg" alt="" title="" border="0"/>
    <p>This is text</p>
</article>
```

And if you need a wrapper for styling purposes - you can use the good ol' `<div>`

> *The `<section>` element is not a generic container element. When an element is needed for styling purposes or as a convenience for scripting, authors are encouraged to use the `<div>` element instead.*

---

**The [section](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/sections.html#the-section-element) element**

An [**article**](http://www.impressivewebs.com/html5-section/) on topic

Comment: so the first and second one are both not good uses of section, right?

Comment: nope.. unless this is a markup for a content slider or tab switcher. In that case you can use <section>-s

Comment: Thanx for the fast reply Zoltan!

Comment: @Zoltan, isn't the ARTICLE tag a mean for representing "a section of content that forms an independent part of a document or site"?
Aside from the ugly naming (Article represents a SECTION...), what's the advantage in using this type of markup if then you need to add more markup for styling needs?

Comment: `<header>` is not required here, since there is only one `<h1-6>`, which is self explanatory.

> *A header element is intended to usually contain the section's heading (an h1–h6 element), but this is not required. The header element can also be used to wrap a section's table of contents, a search form, or any relevant logos.*
— http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/sections.html#the-header-element

See also:
http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/common-idioms.html#sub-head

Answer (score 0):

`<section>` and `<div>` are similar in that they are both used for sectioning. The difference is that if the intended section is for the purpose of styling, `<div>` should be used... but if the section is literally for content then use `<section>`. Have a look at the following quote:

> “When an element is needed only for styling purposes or as a
> convenience for scripting, authors are encouraged to use the div
> element instead…A general rule is that the section element is
> appropriate only if the element’s contents would be listed explicitly…
> ~ WHATWG”

Please note that the general idea of `<section>` is to **list content** like `<li>`. However, the latter is more appropriate for bullet pointing... whereas, the former is more appropriate for things like blog posts, etc.

So, I don't really recommend either of your solutions. You should use something similar to the following:

```
<div class="blog">
    <article class="post">
        <h2 class="post-title">Services</h2>
        <img src="img/foto/testpic1.jpg" alt="" title="" border="0"/>
        <p class="post-excerpt">This is text</p>
    </article>
    <article class="post">
        <h2 class="post-title">Products</h2>
        <img src="img/foto/testpic2.jpg" alt="" title="" border="0"/>
        <p class="post-excerpt">This is text</p>
    </article>
    <article class="post">
        <h2 class="post-title">Contacts</h2>
        <img src="img/foto/testpic3.jpg" alt="" title="" border="0"/>
        <p class="post-excerpt">This is text</p>
    </article>
</div>
```

I hope that helps. All the best.

[ref: https://azizecomm.wordpress.com/2016/01/04/html5-section-vs-div/]